# SQL Server - How to Map values to Main Table

Tags: sql-server

I have this main table:

```
tblMain
-----------------------------------------------
|ClientNo|Country1|Country2|Country3|Agreement|
|--------+--------+--------+--------+---------|
|111123  |SG      |TH      |PH      |OA1      |
|111222  |PH      |MY      |JP      |OA2      |
|323211  |MY      |SG      |PH      |OA3      |
-----------------------------------------------
```

and I have these mapping tables:

```
tblCountry
-------------------------
|CountryCode|CountryName|
|-----------+-----------|
|SG         |Singapore  |
|MY         |Malaysia   |
|PH         |Philippines|
|TH         |Thailand   |
|JP         |Japan      |
-------------------------

tblAgreement
--------------------
|ACode|ADescription|
|-----+------------|
|OA1  |Agreement1  |
|OA2  |Agreement2  |
|OA3  |Agreement3  |
--------------------
```

What I need to achieve is to just return the main table but instead of Codes, I need the mapped name/description.
So for my example, it should look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|ClientNo|Country1   |Country2 |Country3   |Agreement |
|--------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------- |
|111123  |Singapore  |Thailand |Philippines|Agreement1|
|111222  |Philippines|Malaysia |Japan      |Agreement2|
|323211  |Malaysia   |Singapore|Philippines|Agreement3|
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you please help me how to solve this?  Thank you in advance

Comment: can you merge three tables.? and get output of one table.?

Comment: what should you need.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its good to use join rather than sub query in select statement. Please see the below solution.

```
Select 
   Main.ClientNo As ClientNo, 
   CountryA.CountryName, 
   CountryB.CountryName, 
   CountryC.CountryName, 
   A.ADescription As Aggrement
From tblMain AS Main
INNER JOIN tblCountry AS CountryA ON CountryA.CountryCode = Main.Country1
INNER JOIN tblCountry AS CountryB ON CountryB.CountryCode = Main.Country2
INNER JOIN tblCountry AS CountryC ON CountryC.CountryCode = Main.Country3
INNER JOIN tblAgreement A ON Main.Agreement = A.Acode;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
    Main.ClientNum As ClientNo,
    (Select CountryName From tblCountry Where CountryCode = Main.Country1) As Country1,
    (Select CountryName From tblCountry Where CountryCode = Main.Country2) As Country2,
    (Select CountryName From tblCountry Where CountryCode = Main.Country3) As Country3,
    A.Adescrition As Aggrement
From tblMain Main
Inner Join tblAgreement A
On Main.Aggrement = A.Acode;
```